# Laravel Passport login api

Tags: laravel, api, passport

Cuando trato de iniciar sesión con un usuario creado desde mi controlado de api no me lo permite sin embargo si trato de ingresar con un usuario creado desde mi sitio web no tengo ningún problema.
Para crear el usuario estoy usando

```
$input['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
```

Sin embargo cuando intento iniciar sesión el metodo Auth::attempt no me regresa nada.

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
```

Recalcando que cuando ingreso con otro usuario que fue creado desde mi web el código funciona a la perfección.

Dejo el enlace de mi github si es necesario https://github.com/saibothack/dauster

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User; 
use Validator;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

 public $successStatus = 200;

/**
* login api
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);
    }

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
}

/**
* Register api
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required',
        'confirm_password' => 'required|same:password',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);
    }

    $input = $request->all();
    $input['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user = User::create($input);
    $token =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
    return response()->json([
        'token' => $token,
        'user' => $user
    ], $this->successStatus);
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'confirm_password' => 'required|same:password',
    ]);
}

/**
* details api
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function getDetails()
{
   $user = Auth::user();
   return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this->successStatus);
}
}
```

Comment: usas métodos diferentes para el registro mediante api y web? si es así, coloca el código de ambos controladores para poder ver la diferencia. PD: vi el repositorio y en el método `RegisterController@create` estás guardando la clave sin hashear.

Comment: En mi modelo de usuario tengo mi funcion public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {   
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    } y cuando guardo en controlador de api tengo $input['password'] = bcrypt($request->password); que en teoria deberia de realizar la misma acción si no estoy mal? de ahi lo unico que hago es guardar el usuario $user = User::create($input);